# Expand Root in TreeView when ItemSource changed

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, treeview

I have a ChildWindow in a Silverlight 4 App with a TreeView. The ItemSource is binded to an ObservableCollection of Items in a ViewModel. When the window opens the item are loaded from a webservice.

I have only one root node and I need it to be initially expanded. The TreeView even has the extension ExpandToDepth() which seems perfect but I don't know where I can call it. I didn't find an event that occurs after the items are updated from the ItemSource.

I tried using ItemContainerGenerator.ItemChanged and OnItemsChanged in TreeView but they are both executed before the tree view items are generated so the expand commands won't work.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by overriding the PrepareContainerForItemOverride method in TreeView. I wondered why this is just called for the root node but it works.

```
public class ExpandedRootTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        TreeViewItem treeViewItem = element as TreeViewItem;

        if (treeViewItem != null) treeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;

        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

Thanks to everybody who responded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to register for your ObservableCollection's CollectionChange Event and do your actions there.

Comment: Expand actions don't work if i call them in collectionChanged or immediately after setting the itemSoure property in the ViewModel.
I tried the following code:
`var x = treeView.ContainerFromItem(treeView.Items[0]);                      x.IsExpanded = true;`

When I execute it after collectionChanged the root node is already in Items but there is no container yet. Called later from a button click event this works fine.

I somehow need to wait for the treeView to create the containers and add them to the control before executing this.

Comment: If your TreeView item have Item Template then you can register for Loaded event of item and in the handler you can set IsExpanded of TreeView to true.To make sure that you Filter away Loaded event of all other Items you can bind Tag property of your Control to DataContext and in handler also check if Tag of the sender is first element of ItemsSource.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from TreeView and create IsRootItemExpanded property and create same name property in ViewModel. In set accesser check if value  true then call your  method like this ExpandToDepth(1) When itemssource is  need to update  then set IsRootItemExpanded property true. You must to bind IsRootItemExpanded of TreeView to IsRootItemExpanded of ViewModel.